# iMapster's issues with identity in .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, mapster

I want to map a DTO with the identity model (entity).

But I get the following error

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'IdentityUser' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

The code I have written:

```
 public static TypeAdapterConfig MapUserToUpdateUserDto()
 {
     var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
     config.NewConfig<IdentityUser,UpdateUserDto>()
         .Map(e => e.PhoneNumber, d => d.PhoneNumber)
         .Map(e => e.Email, d => d.Email)
         .Map(e => e.UserName, d => d.UserName)
         .Map(e => e.Active, d => d.EmailConfirmed)
         .Map(e => e.Active, d => d.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
         .TwoWays();
     return config;
 }

 public async Task UpdateUser(UpdateUserDto model)
 {
     var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id!);
     user = model.Adapt<IdentityUser>(UserMapster.MapUserToUpdateUserDto());
     
     var resultUpdateUser= await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

     if (resultUpdateUser.Succeeded)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PasswordConfirmed))
         {
             var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
             await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, model.Password);
         }

         var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user!);

         await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
         await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, model.Role!);
     }
 }
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with mapping. It seems like you are reusing the same `DbContext` for multiple operations, which can cause issues, or you are trying to reattach an item to the context that is already tracking it. Take a look at the [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I changed my code to this and my problem was solved

```html
 public async Task UpdateUser(UpdateUserDto model)
 {
     var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id!);
     model.Adapt(user, UserMapster.MapUserToUpdateUserDto());
     var resultUpdateUser = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user!);
     if (resultUpdateUser.Succeeded)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PasswordConfirmed))
         {
             var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
             await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, model.Password);
         }

         var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user!);

         await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
         await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, model.Role!);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Next time, please do not refer to existing answers and reply yourself, as this is disrespectful of the efforts of other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Change your UpdateUser method like below.

Adapt the changes onto `user`, not replacing it.

```
 public async Task UpdateUser(UpdateUserDto model)
 {
     var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id!);
     // Change your code here
     // adapt the changes onto it, not replacing the `user` 
     model.Adapt<IdentityUser>(UserMapster.MapUserToUpdateUserDto());
     
     var resultUpdateUser= await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

     if (resultUpdateUser.Succeeded)
     {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.PasswordConfirmed))
         {
             var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
             await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, model.Password);
         }

         var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user!);

         await _userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user, roles);
         await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, model.Role!);
     }
 }
```